# Не работают ссылки кроме главной Opencart (после переноса)

Tags: php, opencart

Перенес сайт http://edel-wies.com сюда http://1313624.edelwies.web.hosting-test.net/.
Скопировал БД и выгрузил ее на новый хостинг, так же поступил с файла (FTP). Файл конфига редактировал (и в корне, и в папке admin/).

Но не открываются (error 404 Not Found) товары или какие-либо ссылки:
http://1313624.edelwies.web.hosting-test.net/kostyumy-medicinskie/kostyumy-zhenskie
http://1313624.edelwies.web.hosting-test.net/kontakty
И т.д.

При это админка, корзина (http://1313624.edelwies.web.hosting-test.net/index.php?route=checkout/cart), закладки, оформление товара..-  открываются.

Comment: Судя по симптомам не настроен apache или nginx для правильной работы ЧПУ

Comment: Как это исправить? Доступы у меня все есть. Только не пойму что "лечить"?)

Comment: Зависит от того какой у вас хостинг и сервер.

Comment: Хостинг - http://ukraine.com.ua

Comment: У вас есть в корне сайта файл .htaccess ?

Comment: Был, когда переносил довелось его удалить (выбивало ошибку 500).
.htaccess со старого сайта не редактировал, так как не знаю как правильно это сделать.

Comment: Объяснять долго. Без него ничего не заработает. Почитайте тут: https://opencartforum.com/topic/23083-resheno-ne-rabotayut-chpu-opencart/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81687/discussion-between---and--).

Comment: ЧПУ в настройках включены, но когда я их отключаю, тогда все работает корректно. Но это плохо для СЕО. Нужно настроить ЧПУ.
Как понимаю проблема в файле .htaccess

Comment: Да проблема в нём.

Comment: Если точнее вот в этих настройках. RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]

RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA